# Spring and persistence.xml

Tags: spring, web-applications, jpa

Looking at a spring + hibernateJPA tutorial i noticed that the persistence.xml does not have entities defined in it.So how exactly does this entity detection work in the case where we add spring ( 3.0.x) to the mix?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, JPA's EntityManagerFactory will scan your classpath for classes decorated with `@Entity` annotation. JPQL queries will be translated into native SQL queries based on metadata (fields) of these classes.

Comment: I thought that persistence.xml was the equivalent of the hibernate.cfg.xml file. Even if you were using annotations you still had to define the classes. The tutorial i am looking at is this one : https://github.com/chieukam/gwt-spring-hibernate-tutorial  and it does no seem to mention anywhere the classes to be scanned ( like in the case of using hibernate core). So then jpa is scanning classpath the while hibernate is looking exactly after the classes defined in the .cfg.xml file?

Comment: With JPA you can choose to use annotation or declare the entity beans in XML. I suppose if you don't specify what package to be scanned (not sure if you can actually specify) it will scan all your classes and look for `@Entity`. With Hibernate + Spring you can also let Spring do the scanning so you don't have to manually type it in into hibernate.cfg.xml. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html